# Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I've inherited a WordPress site from the guy whose job I took over. This site, it turns out, is actually quite popular, and is updated on a regular basis. This is fantastic, until it comes to the wp-content/uploads folder.

The issue is that when he built the site, he chose to remove the tick from "Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders"... This is fine, apart from the fact that it now has so many files in it, it's impossible to browse into the folder via FTP.

In an effort to try and fix this problem for future uploads, I've now ticked the the box - but that doesn't help me much with my current issue.

So (getting to the point), does anyone know of a plugin, or something along those lines, that I could run on the site, to take all the existing uploads, and sort them into folders (while also updating the database).

I'm sure this is a long shot, but I figured I might as well ask.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of a plugin to do that, but if you have time on your hands, try spinning up a test install on local host and ticking the box and then importing the existing site to that (using the built in wordpress import / export tool, and see if it then has the correct folder structure. *shrug*

Comment: This is worth a try - It could try to get the date metadata from the post the images / other media is attached to in order to create the folders.